# Reset FCM token Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Now I changing FCMToken like this:

```
    InstanceID.deleteID(InstanceID.instanceID())(handler: {_ in})
```

But Xcode asks me to replace this method as it is deprecated
How can I forcefully change FCMToken with not deprecated method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
Messaging.messaging().deleteFCMToken(forSenderID: "your_sender_id", completion: { result in
    Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: "your_sender_id", completion: { (token,error) in
            
        })    
})
```

[deleteFCMToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/Messaging#deletefcmtokenforsenderid:completion:)

[retrieveFCMToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/Messaging#retrievefcmtokenforsenderid:completion:)

Comment: How I can generate new token after deleting?

Comment: check it again.